# Constraints become tightened.

Tags: optimization, terminology, word-problem

Let us think the following optimization problem:

\begin{array}{cl}
\text{minimize} & f(x)\\
\text{subject to} & g(x) \le b_1,\\
& h(x) \ge b_2.
\end{array}

I think we can state as follows: "if $b_1$ gets smaller and $b_2$ gets larger, the constraints get tightened."

---

However, how can I state the similar thing in a different view (focus on the variable $x$)?

Let us start $x_0$, which strictly satisfies both the two constraints, i.e., $$g(x_0)\lt b_1$$ and $$h(x_0) \gt b_2.$$

Now, let us think a situation where $x_0$ is changed to $x_1$, and $x_1$ is satisfying as follows:
$$g(x_1) \gt g(x_0), \qquad g(x_1) \lt b_1$$
and
$$h(x_1) \lt h(x_0), \qquad h(x_1) \lt b_2.$$

In this case, when $x_0$ is changed into $x_1$, is it correct to express "the constraints become more tightened." ?

If so, please comment "yes," but if not, very thank you let me know how to express this situation.

Comment: Thinking locally will mislead you. Think in terms of preimages.

Comment: $x_1$ has smaller slack than $x_0$, but that says nothing about the objective function value